# Two servers: bind exception 1099 when another is trying to start

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have configured two servers and one active mq server.

One server will send a JMS message and the Other server will receive the JMS messages from the active mq server.

Usually we will start active mq server and the servers one by one.

Now one of the server get's started successfully where as the other throws bind exception with 1099 as port already bind.

I have verified none of the process uses the port 1099.

Need a workaround if solution is not possible.

Exception stack trace

```
[Apr 10 09:58:37] [/] WARN  org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext       
(JCLLoggerAdapter.java:359) - Failed to start jmx connector: Cannot bind to URL 
[rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root 
exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]
[Apr 10 09:58:37] [/] WARN  org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext 
(JCLLoggerAdapter.java:359) - Failed to start jmx connector: Cannot bind to URL 
[rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root 
exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]
[Apr 10 09:58:37] [/] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext 
(JCLLoggerAdapter.java:245) - Reason for failed jms connector start
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: 
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is 
java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]
    at
```

Thanks.

Comment: Port 1099 is the RMI Registry port.

Answer (score 2):

As described by the provided stacktrace, both server have Remote JMX enabled on the same port. Use the `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=portNum` option at the JVM level to tune the JMX port, or purely disable Remote JMX by removing the `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` option. These options are usually located in ActiveMQ startup scripts.

Comment: i can remove from the config. is the above is required for receiving and consuming JMS message or not?

Comment: No, JMX is only for monitoring purpose. But it's probably used to monitor the broker its queues and so on.

Comment: so how to remove it..how to disable the same

Comment: To disable JMX? Check my initial comment, edit activemq.bat (or activemq on linux or wrapper.conf as a Windows service), search `com.sun.management.jmxremote` and comment the appropriate line.